# How to efficiently store, check for inclusion and retrieve large amounts of float numbers in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, data-storage

let me describe my problem, so I am creating a simple graphing calculator, the way I did it was that every y coordinate is calculated by putting it into a function f(x) then graphing the point (x, f(x)).

To make things simple for myself, whenever I wanted to shift the graph or zoom in I just adjust the dimensions of the current view and then recalculate all the new points on the screen. For example going from [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txm3b.png) to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhpqS.png) by zooming in and shifting the screen would mean that every single point has been recalculated, for me to get the graph to look like it is formed by actual lines instead of just points I divide the width of the screen into about 1000 ~ 10000 points and plot it and if there are enough points it just looks like lines. These points are made by tuple pairs of floats.

As you could imagine there is a lot of overlap and recalculations that may be slowing down the program and so I am wondering what the best way to calculate a (x, f(x)) point, store it and anytime I change the view of the graph, if that x happens to be in view, be able to retrieve the f(x) and skip the calculation. The thing is there is going to be like thousands and thousands of these points and so I figured using list operations like "i in lst" is not efficient enough.

I am trying to make my graph as fast as possible so any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there will be magic structure more optimized than list. Why isn't this optimized enough for you?

Comment: Also I don't know if it'll be faster to try to use already existing data than to recalculate the points everytime. Maybe check what already existing graph like GeoGebra use to get inspiration

Comment: Python is not a good language for this. The problem calls for high performance and detailed control over data near a hardware level, and Python is a scripting language designed to present some abstract computing, not for high performance or hardware control.

Comment: Circumstances may be such that any particular floating-point value is rarely reused. When a graph is scaled and translated (the view is zoomed and shifted), the x values may land near previous x values but be very different, such as 87.34420000000000072759576141834259033203125 and 87.34420000000142181306728161871433258056640625, which are 100 units apart in the floating-point resolution (assuming IEEE-754 binary64). So you should check that you will actually be reusing many values of x before investing in this solution.

Comment: Thank you all you all bring up good points, I think what I will do is just try to optimize the calculations instead of store points and reuse them to make the program faster. Thanks!